# Form HTML, GET method. URL with multiple keywords

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm building a search page that allows doing a search from 1-4 keywords that through the get method sends to the results page.(eg. for those keywords: one, two tree --> website.com/search/q=one+two+tree)
Right now when I add more keywords and press search it sends to the URL using just the keyword in the text input.
I tried to create a string joining the keywords with the "+" but sitll doesn't work. The following code is what I have tried.
This is a django webapp and in the form.py there is one charfield with an id tag named "add_keyword".
The function that doesn't work is send_keywords()

```
 <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var keywords_array = []
      function getInputValue() {
        if (keywords_array.length<4){
          var ul = document.getElementById("keywords");
          var li = document.createElement("li");
          var inputVal = document.querySelector("#add_keyword").value;

          li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputVal));
          ul.appendChild(li);
          keywords_array.push(inputVal);
        }
        if (keywords_array.length==4){
          console.log("You've added the max number of keywords")
        }
      }
      function send_keywords() {
        query = keywords_array.join("+")
        window.location.href= window.location.href+"/search/q="+query
        return query
      }
    </script>

    <h1>Dulcis in Fundo</h1>
    <h2>Let's coock something, what do you have left?</h2>
    {% block content %}

    <form class="" action="/search/" method="GET">
      <ul id="keywords">
      </ul>
      {{ form }}
      <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();" name="button">add</button>
      <button type="submit" onclick="send_keywords()">Search</button>
    </form>


    {% endblock %}
 </body>
```

Comment: Try `function send_keywords(e) {e.preventDefault();....}`

Comment: @TheMaster `e` is undefined though

Comment: @charlie I see.  I'm unsure how to pass the event from html `onclick` attribute. I guees `.addEventListener()` or `.onclick=` would be better. @OP Without much change to your code, You can try changing `button type` to `"button"` instead of `"submit"`. If I'm right about the problem, that should work.

Comment: @TheMaster you can pass it into function from html ....but agree using addEventListener is better practice https://jsfiddle.net/vzyn1cm8/

Comment: @charlie Thanks. Didn't realize `event` is the keyword.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked